# Reading a binary file and change value but running 64m file takes a long time, every body can help me?

Tags: binary, long-integer, bin

my code is not good, running 64m file takes a long time, can anyone help me? Thanks

For example

```
import re
part = input("in put file bin: ")
input_file = open(part, "rb")
content = input_file.read()
s = content
pattern = b"\xAK"
pattern1 = b"\xCF"
matches = re.finditer(pattern, s)
matches1 = re.finditer(pattern1, s)
for match in matches:
    offset = match.start()
    for match1 in matches1:
        offset1 = match1.start()
        k = offset + 8
        if offset1 == k:
            print("ok")
            content = content.replace(b"\xAK", b"\x08")
            with open("999_output.bin", "wb") as output_file:
                output_file.write(content)
```